# cocos2dx - GameOver scene on ingame scene

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, scene, cocos2d-x-3.0

When the game over condition is satisfied I want to show a game over menu. This menu I have implemented via Scene. Now I wonder how I can show game over scene on top of ingame, without covering all the ingame scene. I want to make it look like a popup. How I should do that?

Comment: add it to your scene, make sure it doesn't cover the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout part "Design and Implement the Game Over Layer" in the following tutorial at: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/tutorial/parkour-game-with-javascript/chapter9/en

It wrote in js, but i think the process with Cpp is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just change your CCScene to CCLayer. Very few changes will be required in the code. 
Then the part where you use the CCDirector to replace scene with your Game Over scene just initialize your Layer.